# carouFredSel Scroll Multiple Items On Next/Prev

Tags: jquery, joomla, caroufredsel

I am having trouble with my carouFredSel, currently it shows 4 items at a time, when someone clicks the next or previous buttons I would like it to scroll to the next set of 4 items. I am very new to using carouFredSel and despite checking the advanced documentation I could not implement a solution.

Also the carousel is created via a module in Joomla if that helps clarify details.

Below are some of the variety of ways I have tried to implement a fix.

```
jQuery(".brands ul.slides").carouFredSel({ 
            scroll : {
                items   : 4
            }
            next : {
                button  : '.slider-controls li a.next',
                items   : 4
            },
            prev : {
                button  : '.slider-controls li a.prev',
                items   : 4
            },
            pagination : {
                items   : 4
            }
        });
```

None of these seem to have had any effect on the amount of items scrolled when clicking next or previous. I have tried each and everyone one of them by themselves and in different combinations. As this is my first post to stackoverflow I am unable to post a picture to help clarify details, if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is this something you have converted into a custom module or was this a pre-made 3rd party module that you downloaded?

Comment: @Lodder

It is a pre-made module that came with a template I purchased. You can see it here - [Template Demo](http://imbus.ws-theme.com/) and scroll to the brands section on the homepage.

Comment: A template you have actually paid for with money. I'm not going to beat around the bush, but do you not think it would be best to contact the developer seeing as you have paid for this?

Comment: @Lodder I contacted the developer/company and they said to check out the API's and gave me a link to the documentation.

Comment: Jeez, paid support and that's all they have to say. Not helpful in the slightest :/ Are you sure you're not referring to WS-Flexslider as I can't see carouFredSel on their support page. It might also be an option in the module parameters so be sure to check there too.

Comment: @Lodder Yep because I wanted to automate the testimonial slider and both are from the same module, "please check the Documentation for CarouFredSel which we have used :-))" was the response. As for module options there is only one, switch between clients/brands or testimonails.